# Why am I not being able to save my addresses?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to develop an e-commerce website with Django. I want to use ajax to handle my checkout form. When I added Ajax, after filling out the form and clicking the submit button, I am seeing that my form and data is not getting saved by going into my admin.

It's also not being redirected to `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(redirect))+"?address_added=True")`, rather it's being redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=u6hDPBVuOZbDmoHvRFWb2PvfK1YamCIKGSaDkKdVTviWvJODgY5lM6rKppoW1oeP&address=123+Main+Street&address2=&state=MA&country=USA&zipcode=55525&phone=%28877%29+314-0742&billing=on`.

What's wrong?

My accounts.views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.contrib.auth import logout, login, authenticate
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm, UserAddressForm
from django.urls import reverse

def add_user_address(request):
    try:
        redirect = request.GET.get("redirect")
    except:
        redirect = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserAddressForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_address = form.save(commit=False)
            new_address.user = request.user
            new_address.save()
            if redirect is not None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(redirect))+"?address_added=True")
    else:
        raise Http404
```

My urls.py:

```
path('ajax/add_user_address/', accounts_views.add_user_address, name='ajax_add_user_address')
```

My checkout.html:

```
<div class="content-section">
    <form method="POST" action='{% url "ajax_add_user_address" %}?redirect=checkout'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">   
            {{ address_form|crispy }}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark" value="Place Order"/>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

My orders.views.py:

```
from accounts.forms import UserAddressForm
from accounts.models import UserAddress

@login_required()
def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        the_id = None
        return redirect(reverse("myshop-home"))

    try:
        new_order = Order.objects.get(cart=cart)
    except Order.DoesNotExist:
        new_order = Order(cart=cart)
        new_order.cart = cart
        new_order.user = request.user
        new_order.order_id = id_generator()
        new_order.save()
    except:
        return redirect(reverse("cart"))


    address_form = UserAddressForm()


    if new_order.status == "Finished":
        #cart.delete()
        del request.session['cart_id']
        del request.session['items_total']
        return redirect(reverse("cart"))


    context = {"address_form": address_form, "cart": cart}
    template = "orders/checkout.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: Remove those bare `except:` s, you'll never figure out what exceptions you're getting otherwise.

Comment: This question appears in a sequence of 11 questions from the same author on the same, or nearly the same topic. Many of these are copy-paste duplicate of each other, and will serve to waste the time of helpful readers who have not checked how many times the question has been re-asked.