# Why am I not being able to save my addresses? Django/ajax

Tags: python, django, ajax

I'm trying to develop an e-commerce website with Django. I want to use ajax to handle my checkout form. When I added Ajax, after filling out the form and clicking the submit button, I am seeing that my form and data is not getting saved by going into my admin.

It's also not being redirected to `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(redirect))+"?address_added=True")`, rather it's being redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=u6hDPBVuOZbDmoHvRFWb2PvfK1YamCIKGSaDkKdVTviWvJODgY5lM6rKppoW1oeP&address=123+Main+Street&address2=&state=MA&country=USA&zipcode=55525&phone=%28877%29+314-0742&billing=on`.

What's wrong?

My accounts.views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.contrib.auth import logout, login, authenticate
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm, UserAddressForm
from django.urls import reverse


def add_user_address(request):
    try:
        redirect = request.GET.get("redirect")
    except:
        redirect = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserAddressForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_address = form.save(commit=False)
            new_address.user = request.user
            new_address.save()
            if redirect is not None:
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(str(redirect))+"?address_added=True")
    else:
        raise Http404
```

My urls.py:

```
path('ajax/add_user_address/', accounts_views.add_user_address, name='ajax_add_user_address'),
```

My checkout.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'ajax_add_user_address' %}?redirect=checkout">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">   
        {{ address_form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit">Place Order</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Wilful and time-wasting duplicate: [Why am I not being able to save my addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61233992/why-am-i-not-being-able-to-save-my-addresses)

Comment: This question appears in a sequence of 11 questions from the same author on the same, or nearly the same topic. Many of these are copy-paste duplicate of each other, and will serve to waste the time of helpful readers who have not checked how many times the question has been re-asked.